# Click event not fired in floating button if over an element scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

When having a button (or any other element, positioned `absolute` or `fixed`) on top of an element with a scrolling area which is actively scrolling (i.e. for example it's decelerating) it seems that the button doesn't receive the `click` event when clicked.

It seems that when clicking (or touching) the scrollable element area, the scrolling is interrupted, but the button on top of it doesn't receive any event.

I've debugged events for the floating element in Chrome and the only thing received is a `mousewheel` event.

This is particularly annoying if the button is a navigation button, as you have to click twice to exit the page if the content is decelerating (as opposed to once when the content is still).

I browsed many times for a solution but never found a clue about this behaviour and how to avoid it, so any thoughts will be appreciated.

Sample code here: https://codepen.io/djibarian/pen/bGLoYxY

If you scroll the red box and while still scrolling due to inertia try to click the button, you only manage to stop the scrolling in the box, but the button doesn't receive the click event.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, please share your code with us, so we can help you.

Comment: Hi @robertp, I added some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your code, but it's worth checking following.

1. Check if any element overlaps the positioned fixed element.
2. Make sure the stacking context of the element is correct.

Try adding a higher z-index and see if it's working. If it works then it's worth changing the dom element order for precedence.

Comment: Hi @Oshan, I added some sample code.